# Django navigation issue

Tags: django, url, hyperlink, navigation

I am writing a navigation header in django. And i am having problem navigations between urls that i created.

urls.py

```
url(r'^home/$', home_page, name="home_url"),
url(r'^about/$', about_page, name="about_url"),
```

template

```
<a href="home_url>Home</a>
<a href="About_url>About</a>
```

When I click on this i am getting something like. `mysite.com/home/home_url`
How should i configure it so i can navigate to the correct link?

Answer (score 4):

Read [Naming urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns) docs:

**For your code:**

```
<a href="{% url 'home_url' %}" >Home</a>
<a href="{% url 'about_url' %}">About</a>
```

Comment: remove quotes if you use django < 1.5